# Using a Facebook app to post to a page wall. Does it show on followers streams?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a Facebook application, my web site uses the C# API to post some updates, using the [pageid]/feed approach.  If I publish through Facebook itself, I instantly get a lot of Likes and Comments, posting the same item through the app gets no attention at all.

This is leading me to think that if I post through an app, the update doesn't show in the stream of my page followers?  Only on the wall of my page?  Is this the case, if so, is there anyway to make sure posts by my app appear in their streams?  Or is there something I'm not considering or understanding?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a currently open bug regarding API posts made as the page which have link or photo attachments getting reduced distribution - i'm not aware of the current status of it though.

In general, 'posting to the page as the page' via the API (an important distinction from 'posting to the page as you' - ensure you're using the page's access token and not an access token of one of the admins) should appear in the News Feeds of the page followers exactly as if you'd posted the same content using the www.facebook.com interface

Comment: Ah ok.  My post is indeed a link, so I'll switch this out to be a regular post for now.  Your answer was absolutely what I was after.  Thank you.